# NSButton blue highlight

Tags: cocoa, highlight, nsbutton

i want to make on/off gradient `NSButton` but with blue highlight like `NSTabView` select buttons. 
Is it possible to make this easy way? 
Or i should draw this manually?  
if i should draw this manually what is the best way to do this? (`CIFilter` or just `NSGradient`)

thanks.

Comment: From your comments on my other answer (now deleted), it seems you want neither a gradient button (in the sense of what IB calls a “gradient button”) nor a blue highlight like NSTabView/NSSegmentedControl has. The example you gave was the pair of buttons “in iPhoto book editing mode at the top (Pages/Images select)”. That would be a button with a gray gradient background, showing *the image* highlighted in blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make that yourself with a custom subclass of NSButtonCell.

Comment: and what will this subclass include?

Answer (score 1):

To do that in IB(Interface Builder) you simply need set the button's key equivalent to "Return" using
the popup menu (or type in \R into the key equivalent field).